# Single-row subquery returns more than one row - SQL Query

Tags: sql, select

I am writing a SQL Query that returns name of the product that is used the most.

When I run it, I get the **Single-row subquery returns more than one row** error and I do now know how to fix it.

This is my query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW mostUsed AS
SELECT a.article_name, SUM(p.quantity) AS numberOfItems
FROM ARTICLE a, ITEM p
WHERE p.fk_id_article = a.id_article
GROUP BY a.article_name
HAVING SUM(p.quantity) >= (SELECT MAX(p.quantity) FROM ITEM);

SELECT ARTICLE_NAME, numberOfItems
FROM mostUsed
WHERE numberOfItems = (SELECT MAX(numberOfItems) FROM mostUsed);
```

Any help on fixing it is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: could you just change the `(SELECT MAX(p.quantity) FROM ITEM)` that instead of `p.quantity` you just use `quantity` without the `p`?

Comment: @GabrielAmram ofcourse lol, such and amateur mistake. It runs perfectly now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `outerquery` column's can be referred inside `subquery`.

```
(SELECT MAX(p.quantity) FROM ITEM)
```

Since you used `p.quantity` value is fetched from the outer table `ITEM p` instead of `Item` table in `subquery` and the outer `Item` table is grouped by `a.article_name` so it returned more than one row.

so remove alias `P` from the `subquery` your problem will be fixed

```
SELECT a.article_name, SUM(p.quantity) AS numberOfItems
FROM ARTICLE a, ITEM p
WHERE p.fk_id_article = a.id_article
GROUP BY a.article_name
HAVING SUM(p.quantity) >= (SELECT MAX(quantity) FROM ITEM)
```